# Creating a dictionary in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to create a dictionary using PowerShell. Actually I am using command to get all the services.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service |
   ? {$_.name -like '*SQLSERVER*' -or $_.name -like '*ReportServer*'} |
   select systemname, Name, state, startmode, startname
```

and I am getting below output

```
systemname : WJNJINPC0BF62E
Name       : LanmanServer
state      : Running
startmode  : Auto
startname  : LocalSystem

systemname : WJNJINPC0BF62E
Name       : msiserver
state      : Stopped
startmode  : Manual
startname  : LocalSystem

systemname : WJNJINPC0BF62E
Name       : TMBMServer
state      : Running
startmode  : Manual
startname  : LocalSystem
```

I need to arrange each block as dictionary in Python: say for example

```
{ 'systemname': 'WJNJINPC0BF62E', 'Name': 'LanmanServer', 'state': 'Running', 'startmode': 'Auto', 'startname': 'LocalSystem' }
```

Is there any way to do it using PowerShell script?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve here. Do you want the data *displayed* the way Python would display a dictionary? Do you need the data as an *actual* dictionary? Why? What do you need this for?

Comment: If you need this in Python and only need the exact syntax due to that I'd say the better option would be `ConvertTo-Json` and import it on the other end.

Comment: @Joey : It's still not clear to me what you mean exactly. Can you please clarify your question? Usually a Dictionary object is created by New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary (followed by the type of dictionary) or in PS5 by using the New() method to call the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output format should already by a list/dictionary state. You can save the output to an object by using

```
$test = get-wmiobject -Class win32_service | ?{$_.name -like '*SQLSERVER*' -or $_.name -like 'ReportServer'} | select systemname, Name, state, startmode, startname
```

This will give you a list of dictionary objects which can be accessed similar to `$test[0].systemname`. If you want it to be like the python format, you can the following

```
$pythonFormat = convertto-json $test
```

Comment: The output is a list of custom objects, not dictionaries.